# como reemplazar mis if para reducir código?

Tags: java, spring, condiciones

Tengo el siguiente código que realiza validaciones, pero hay alguna otra forma 
de reducir el codigo o de no utilizar varios ifs

```html
public DatosSalida consultarDatos(DatosaEntrada entrada){
 DatosSalida salida = new DatosSalida();
 
 InformacionAceptada  infAcept = InformacionRepository.buscaFolio(entrada.getFolio());
 
 if(!entrada.getCurpValido.equals(infoAcept.getCurp())){
  salida.serResultado("Rechazo")
  salida.setValidacion("02");
 }else if(entrada.getTipoTrabajador != 1){
  salida.serResultado("Rechazo")
  salida.setValidacion("02");
 }else if(!entrada.getClave.equals(infAcept.getClave)){
  salida.serResultado("Rechazo")
  salida.setValidacion("02");
 }else if(infAcept.getEstatusValido != 1){
  salida.serResultado("Rechazo")
  salida.setValidacion("02");
 
 }else{
  salida.serResultado("Aceptado")
  salida.setValidacion("01");
  salida.setDatoVerificador(1);
 
 }
 

 return salida;
}
```

Comment: no sabes usar switch case??

Comment: @abrahamhs no, como seria?

Answer (score 3):

Cuando las condiciones haran un mismo objectivo puedes unirlas con operador logico `OR`. simbolicamente es `||`

> OR lógico: verdadero (true) si uno o los dos operandos son verdaderos (true)

```
if(!entrada.getCurpValido.equals(infoAcept.getCurp()) || entrada.getTipoTrabajador != 1 || !entrada.getClave.equals(infAcept.getClave) || infAcept.getEstatusValido != 1){
    salida.serResultado("Rechazo")
    salida.setValidacion("02");
}else{
    salida.serResultado("Aceptado")
    salida.setValidacion("01");
    salida.setDatoVerificador(1);
}
```

Puedes documentarte un poco más [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-6957/chp-typeopexpr/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

La forma de mejorar ese código en subdividiendo cada problema en funciones separadas. En este caso, podríamos tomar cada comparación/validación como un problema independiente, asi como la generación de la salida de rechazo y aceptación.

En este caso seria asi

```
public bool CurpValido(DatosaEntrada entrada, InformacionAceptada infAcept)
{
    return entrada.getCurpValido.equals(infoAcept.getCurp());
}

public bool tipoTrabajadorEquals(DatosaEntrada entrada, int tipo)
{
    return entrada.getTipoTrabajador != tipo;
}

public bool claveValida(DatosaEntrada entrada, InformacionAceptada infAcept)
{
    return entrada.getClave.equals(infAcept.getClave);
}

public bool statusValido(DatosaEntrada entrada, int status)
{
    return infAcept.getEstatusValido != status;
}

public bool entradaInValida(DatosaEntrada entrada, InformacionAceptada infAcept)
{
    return !CurpValido(entrada, infAcept) || tipoTrabajadorEquals(entrada, 1) || !claveValida(entrada, infAcept) || statusValido(entrada, 1);
}

public Salida generarRechazo() {
    DatosSalida salida = new DatosSalida();
    salida.serResultado("Rechazo");
    salida.setValidacion("02");
    return salida;
}

public Salida generarAceptado() {
    DatosSalida salida = new DatosSalida();
    salida.serResultado("Aceptado");
    salida.setValidacion("01");
    salida.setDatoVerificador(1);
    return salida;
}

public DatosSalida consultarDatos(DatosaEntrada entrada)
{
    InformacionAceptada infAcept = InformacionRepository.buscaFolio(entrada.getFolio());

    DatosSalida salida = (entradaInValida(entrada, infAcept) ? generarRechazo() : generarAceptado();

    return salida;
}
```

Como podes ver, la función `consultarDatos()` queda mucho mas sencilla y entendible. Por otro lado, la función `entradaInValida()` permite describir de manera concisa las diferentes validaciones/condiciones por la cual la entrada es invalida gracias al nombre amigable de cada una de las funciones secundarias de validación.

La idea es que cada función tenga la menor responsabilidad posible, en este caso, las funciones de validación solo validan, la de consultar datos solo sabe consultar datos y devuelve una respuesta pero el cómo genera la respuesta es delegada a otras funciones que a su vez sólo saben cómo generar el objeto DatosSalida sin interesarle que pasó antes ni que va a pasar después.

No queda el código mucho mas corto pero si mucho mas entendible y fácil de extender (si al día de mañana hay que agregar otras 10 condiciones) y mantener en el futuro.

Dejo a tu criterio colocar los nombres de las funciones mas acordes a tus necesidades.